# Animate pie diagram as a background of TextView from one state to another

Tags: android, background, android-animation, textview, android-shape

I am setting the background of a `TextView`in android as a pie diagram. I have used a `LayerDrawable` of `ArcShape`(s) to do so and set it as the background. Here is the code for that:

```
final ShapeDrawable arcGreen = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(-90, correctAngle));
arcGreen.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.feedback_score_3));

final ShapeDrawable arcRed = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(-90 + correctAngle, 360 - correctAngle));
arcRed.getPaint().setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.feedback_score_1));

final Drawable[] layer = {arcGreen, arcRed, mask};
final LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(layer);

mSvaraLayout.getChildAt(i).setBackground(ld);
```

Now, what I want to do is to animate this background when the value of `correctAngle` changes. One of the options that I see is to use `ValueAnimator` and go from the initial value to the new `correctValue` and each time inside the `onAnimationUpdate()` callback I create a new `LayerDrawable` object with the changed values and set it as a background. Other way could have been to get all the `Drawables`(s) in the background first(which are the `ShapeDrawable(<ArcShape>)`objects and then set the angles of the arcs. But I guess there is no way to do so. Is there any other way to achieve this?